# Continuous Form, Delete button for selected Rows

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form like so :

[image: screenshot2.png]

When I select multiple rows I want my delete button at the footer of the form to delete all the records I have selected. It just ends up deleting the first row I selected. Trying to research vba code for functions that gets the selected records, and all i came across was,

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord`

That doesn't choose all the selected entries. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can delete records one-by-one without code by clicking on one record's record selector (gray rectangle to the left of each client name) and pressing the delete key. You can do the same with multiple adjacent records. If you want to delete multiple non-adjacent records, you need to make a big change: adding a field like chkDelete to the source table and adding a bound checkbox. With that built, you can call a delete query that deletes all rows where chkDelete=True.

Comment: Hmm I see, I'm trying to add a checkboxes, but when I select one check box all of the checkboxes get checked, how would I go about avoiding this

Comment: @Thatdude1 That happens if you add an unbound Checkbox control to the form. The control is not bound to a field in each record, so the state of the control is shared among all rows in the continuous form. That's why pteranodon said that you need to add a Yes/No field to the table and bind the Checkbox control to that field.

Comment: You could set the `Locked` property to `Yes` for all controls except the selection checkbox.